# $f$ is a non-constant polynomial, $A $ is a set of measure zero, Is this true that $m(f^{-1}A)=0$, where $m$ stands for the Lebesgue measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a non-constant polynomial, and let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a set of measure zero, Is this true that $m(f^{-1}A)=0$, where $m$ stands for the Lebesgue measure.

If $A$ is a countable set, it is easy to see that $Cardinality (f^{-1}A) \leq Cardinality (\mathbb{N} * \mathbb{N})$ and it means that $m(f^{-1}A)=0$.

My problem in proving that this is true, is sets like Cantor set, whose measure is zero but is uncountable.

Any hints or ideas is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: This is a nice one. How did you find this question?

Comment: This is a part of my solution to another problem, so I "need" this to be true, otherwise my attempt would not be the best.

Original Question is a very general statement : If $E$ is a measurable set, and $f$ is a polynomial, Prove that $f^{-1}E$ is measurable.

Comment: You can probably take advantage of the fact that a polynomial is invertible almost everywhere with continuous inverse.

Comment: @AlexBecker Thanks ! you mean "locally" invertible ?

Comment: @Alex Becker : Do you mean locally invertible? I mean, I thought you were saying something smart for a moment, and then I realized polynomials are $n$ to $1$ in general, with $n$ the degree of $f$.

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity : Heh, lol. I believe he does.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva That's what I meant. I think you can piece together the local inverses to get only finitely many neighborhoods total, but I haven't worked it out.

Comment: Thanks you guys ! I'm gonna try that idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following @AlexBecker idea :

Suppose $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, so it has at most $n-1$ pieces, each of which is monotone. Partition $E$ such that $E=E_1 \cup E_2 \cup ... \cup E_{n-1}$ such that $f$ restricted to each $E_k$ is (strictly) monotone. We can say $$f=f|_{E_1}+f|_{E_2}+...+f|_{E_{n-1}}$$
Therefore we have : $$f^{-1}A=(f|_{E_1})^{-1}A \ \bigsqcup \ (f|_{E_2})^{-1}A \ \bigsqcup \ ... \bigsqcup \ (f|_{E_{n-1}})^{-1}A \ $$
If I show that for each $1 \leq k \leq n-1 $ the set $C_k=(f|_{E_{k}})^{-1}A$ has zero measure, we are done.
Suppose that's not the case, i.e. $mC_k=r_k>0$, and note that since $f|_{E_{k}}$ is strictly monotone on $E_k$, we can find $m_k>0$ (monotone increasing) or $m_k<0$ (monotone decreasing) such that $f'(x) \geq m_k$ for all $x \in E_k$. Therefore we have that $$|m_k| \leq \frac{m \left[f|_{E_{k}}C_k \right]}{m C_k} \Longrightarrow 0 < r_km_k \leq  m \left[f|_{E_{k}} C_k \right] \leq mA \ \ \ (by \ \ Monotonicity)$$
A contradiction. Therefore $$mf^{-1}A=m(f|_{E_1})^{-1}A \ + \ m(f|_{E_2})^{-1}A \ + \ ... + \ m(f|_{E_{n-1}})^{-1}A \ = 0 + 0 + ... + 0 = 0 $$

Comment: @AlexBecker Is it Okay ?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Is it Okay ?

Comment: non-constant ${}{}$

Comment: @mike Thanks ! I will make the correction in the statement of the question. Indeed, I was interested in non-constant polynomilals.

Comment: How about multivariate polynomials?

Comment: @timur well, I'm not sure about that ,but here It is assumed that $A \subset \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity : $f'$ has at most $n-1$ zeros, which means that you have at most $n$ pieces which are monotone, not $n-1$. And you need to assume that $E$ doesn't have points $x$ where $f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: What is $E$? It just randomly appears.

Comment: $f'$ is not bounded below for sure ; between two roots, say $a$ and $b$ with $a < b$, $\lim_{x \searrow a} f'(x) = f'(a) = 0$. If you are not between two roots but between $+/- \infty$ and a root, then converging to the root makes the derivative converge to zero. You're looking for an upper bound (using either the compacity argument for $[a,b]$ with $a$ and $b$ roots, or exhaust $]-\infty,a]$ and $[b,\infty[$ with a sigma-finiteness argument).